# How to keep eliminate multiple records from a query?

Tags: ms-access

ok so I have this database with 3 tables in it:

**Students:** (with 2 fields) **ID,** **Names** 
**Months:** (with 4 fields) **ID**, **Months,** **StudentID,** **Fees** 
**Student_Month** (with 3 fields) **ID,** **StudentID,** **MonthID**

as you might expect, they are related as in the pic below:

http://i62.tinypic.com/o52tcm.jpg

now, when I create a simple query with 3 fields:
**student Name,** **Month,** and **Fees** 
even thought I get what I want, the records are repeated for each student
i.e if a student, say Linda has paid 3 months of fees, her name is repeated 3 times in the query next to her fees and months like this:

[image]

here I want 3 things done: 
**a): how do i get the query to show only 1 record for each student?**

**b): How do I get the query to show only 1 record for each student while showing all the 12 months that they have paid the fees for?**

***c):All I want is a query to get me the students names and their fees next to each 12 months with no repetitive records for each student or months***

PS: I can sense that there is some technical flaw with my current design, but I have tried almost everything that I knew (10 hours) but I can't get it to yield my desired results. so if anyone could please show me how to get this done, It would be much more appreciated. thanks in advance!

PSS:  doing "unique values : yes" in the property sheet settings of query does not work for me.

Comment: how about having mysql enforce primary keys or unique indexes and not have front end ms-access gui deal with it. Ms-access also allows you to run a query that does a join. Group by student id (showing name)

Comment: are you using mysql? are you using access as a front end for a mysql database? or are you just using access?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no knowledge of getting things in ms-acess done with Mysql. I was hopping I could find some GUI workaround to this @DrewPierce

Comment: I'm using ms access 2010 - more specifically, only the GUI part of it @Barranka

Comment: How would you collapse the data? If you want to get only one row per name, then you have to decide how to collapse the rows... either use a pivot query or aggregate the data. If all you want is to "hide" the data, then you won't be able to do so in a data sheet... maybe in a report. A database table / query *is not* a worksheet

Comment: Are you using the query designer or writing a VBA query?

Comment: I want this query to show only one record for each student so that later when designing the form, I can put a "combo box" both for names and months. right now when I do that, even though it works, but again both the combo boxes for name and months are populated with multiple versions of the same name & months just like in the main query! @Barranka

Comment: yes I'm doing it all in the good old query designer @LynneDavidson

Answer (score 1):

Your data values are in the wrong tables, and you need to do some juggling in the query designer..  See if this helps you get where you need to go:
[image]  Let me know